# Expectation of E(g(X + c))

Tags: time-series, expected-value

This is from Time Series Analysis from WS Wei

If,

[image]

where [image]

**Approach** - 
We have to find Var(Z)

[image]

So,

[image]

since [image] and [image]

I have simulated this scenario on computer with [image] and the answer seems to be ~ 0.5

Is my approach correct? Further, I'm not able to move ahead with the integral. Any help is greatly appreciated

**SAS Code:**

```
/* Generate time series data - 20 time points. repeated samples of 20 points each */

data TS2; 
omega = constant("pi")/4;
 do runs = 1 to 5000; /* each run is a 20 time sample */
   do t = 1 to 20;
    A = rand('NORMAL');
    pi = constant("pi");
    /* rand('UNIFORM') generates uniform random variates from (0, 1) */
    theta = 2*constant("pi")*rand('UNIFORM') + -constant("pi");
    Z = A*sin((omega*t)+theta);
    output;
    end;
   end;
  run;

  data dssub1(rename = (Z = Z1));
  set TS2(where = (t = 1)); /* Retrieve t = 1 for each of the runs */
  by runs;
  if first.runs;
  run;

  proc univariate data = dssub1;
  var Z1;
  run;
```

Variance - 0.49702

Next, Part B of the question - find if [image] are independent

For this we need to check, 
[image]

RHS is zero since [image] = 0 for any t

*LHS:*

[image] - (a)

Considering, [image] and using the identity

[image]

(a) = [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
(since the second term is zero)

This means they are not independent? Are the steps okay or anything wrong. Please let me know.

Comment: Hint: when you replace $\sin^2$ in the integral by $\cos^2$ you will get the same answer, because $\cos$ is a phase-shifted sine and the integral is over an entire period.  Sum the two integrals and simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give you a hint:

$$\int \sin^2(x) dx = \frac x2-\frac{\sin(2x)}4+c$$

Comment: and whuber thanks. I now can solve the integral to 1/2 and Var(Z) interestingly does not depend on either omega nor t.  But wanted to know if my approach for Var(Z) is correct? Let me know. thanks. Next will check if Zt are independent.

Comment: Two things are not clear for me: 1) no explanation for $\omega$. 2) $\theta \sim U()$ form -a to a. What is that a.

Comment: Omega is a fixed constant, t is time index. So, our random variable Z is actually subscripted  - Zt.  Theta is uniformly distributed over -pi and +pi.

Comment: Then I have no problem with your approach. Just need to finish the last step.

Comment: Could you please comment on the code logic too? What the code does is 1) Stimulates 20 time points of Z1 - Z20  2) Repeat step 1) say 5000 times 3) From these 5000 realizations for say, Z1 get Var(Z1) which as we can see from the math equals 0.5 and remains same for all Zt.

Comment: "theta = 2*constant("pi")*rand('UNIFORM') + -constant("pi");" do not need that "+". After data step TS2, "proc means data=ts2; class t; var Z; run;" will generate  the means at the different point of t.

Comment: To check independence, compare $Z_t$ and $Z_{t + 2\pi/\omega}.$

Comment: @whuber - I have included check for independence - could you please check?

Comment: Your check is invalid: independence means something much stronger than multiplicativity of expectations.  The lack of independence should be obvious: you won't need to do any calculation.

Comment: @whuber, Just for my clarity, I should have checked whether joint density of both equals product of their marginal densities. Multiplicity of expectations only prove that they are mean independent but isn't this check sufficient to say they are not independent. Correct me if I'm wrong